# Every time I plug in my phone via USB it automatically mounts the SD card

Tags: 2.2-froyo, motorola-droid, usb, cyanogenmod

I have a Motorla Droid running CM6 (essentially Android 2.2).  I'm connecting to Windows 7 machines via USB.  Every time I plug in my phone via USB it automatically mounts the SD card as external storage.

How can I stop this behavior?  I haven't really noticed when it started, sometime after I installed CM6?

Comment: fyi, my droid running stock 2.2 doesn't auto-mount.

Comment: I kind of borrowed your question http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15380/every-time-i-plug-in-my-phone-via-usb-it-automatically-mounts-the-sd-card-xperi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently the [Winamp](http://www.appbrain.com/app/winamp/com.nullsoft.winamp) app has an `Enable auto-mount` setting that is by default set to true.  Problem resolved.

Comment: Also I found in the past that the DoubleTwist app annoyingly does this too.

Comment: I believe in both cases the publishers of these apps consider this a helpful feature.

Comment: I find it highly annoying because I usually just plug in my phone via usb to charge, not mount as a drive

Comment: Well, at least there is the option to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

While connected via USB, you will notice a USB icon on notification bar.

Drag the notification bar down, you will see a "USB connection" item. Click it.

Select "none" or "nothing" (I'm not sure about the option name in english, because my Motorola Milestone is in portuguese).

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. His is auto-mounting, before he picks anything from the notification item.

Comment: You only have to do this once. The next time you connect your phone via USB, it won't auto-mount.