# Every time I plug in my phone via USB it automatically mounts the SD card (Xperia Arc version)

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, sd-card, sony-xperia-arc

I have almost this question:

[Every time I plug in my phone via USB it automatically mounts the SD card](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2544/every-time-i-plug-in-my-phone-via-usb-it-automatically-mounts-the-sd-card)

> I have a Motorla Droid running CM6 (essentially Android 2.2). I'm
>   connecting to Windows 7 machines via USB. Every time I plug in my
>   phone via USB it automatically mounts the SD card as external storage.

Except I have a Xperia Arc with version 2.3.4, and have neither Winamp or DoubleTwist installed (given as culprits in the other question).

This behaviour started when I updated to 2.3.4 (I don't know exactly what version I had before).

How can I stop it?

Edit:
I've no "Connect to PC" section in the settings, nor can I find this setting in other sections such as "Storage"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `Settings->Sony Ericsson->Connectivity` and un-check `Auto connect in MSC`.

Comment: Thanks. A bit of strange location to put that setting though.

Comment: @Bart Happy to help... :) I too had to work around the android to find out this option when I had faced this problem...

Comment: Is this possible with Samsung / Android 2.3.6 (I don't find Auto connect!)