# Auto-mount microSD when plugging phone to computer with USB

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, internal-storage, usb-connection-mode, usb-mass-storage

In short: How to **automatically mount the microSD-card as a storage drive when I plug the phone to computer?**

---

When I want to connect my Android 2.3.6 phone (with USB cable) to computer (Windows 7 / PC), I have to

1. unlock the phone (slide finger on screen)
2. slide to make the **top notification panel** appear
3. click on `USB connected / select to copy files to/from your computer` in the notification panel

[image]

4. click on "Connect USB storage"

[image]

5. Accept the warning message

[image]

6. wait...

*So many steps!*

Instead of all these steps, I would like **auto-mount the microSD-card as a storage drive when I plug the phone to computer**. How to do that?

Comment: The first question is: are you willing to forgo locking it? I don't think there is an automatable way around this (for good reason). Second: PC or Mac or Linux?

Comment: @LivedWithOtters No I don't want to forgot about locking screen... 2nd question: PC Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer in the comments (apologies for not catching the OS in your initial post), you're going to still have to unlock by hand.  Past that step, I would recommend trying Macrodroid, Tasker, or other automation apps to see if they can help out. I've not used them to automate connections like this, but they are great in other situations, so I have great hope for a solution here for you.

Comment: Shouldn't there be an option in *Settings* like "Auto-mount on USB connect?" I can't find it, but it seems that it exists on some phone running Android : http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15380/every-time-i-plug-in-my-phone-via-usb-it-automatically-mounts-the-sd-card-xperi?rq=1

Comment: @Basj What happens when you change that setting to msc? Can you skip login on the phone and see it directly with the computer?

Comment: I can't even find this option @LivedWithOtters... I don't have "Connectivity" menu...

Comment: @Basj Do you have this Settings > Applications > Development on your version of phone/OS?

Comment: Yes @LivedWithOtters, but I only have "USB debugging" (on), "Stay awake" (off), "Allow mock locations" (off) and sadly, no other option here.